# Eclipse stuck in server status "starting"

Tags: eclipse, startup, application-server

I'm using Eclipse (4.2) and am trying to start a JBossAS 7.
I had this problem with the status being allegedly stuck in "starting" before and it was always due to some other process occupying the port 8080.

But not this time, port 8080 is free, so I am a little clueless what to do next. Is it possible to enable a more detailed logging in Eclipse to see what it's acutally waiting for?

Comment: Doesn't the server log contains any errors?

Comment: No, the server is starting up fine, only Eclipse doesn't notice it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, just figured it out.

I did exchange a certificate which is passed as a startup option to eclipse and the new certificate also has a new password... which I didn't change. Now everything's fine.